# js array to stream for azure blobservice createBlockBlobFromStream

Tags: javascript, azure, stream, azure-blob-storage

I have an array and I want to upload the content to azure using createBlockBlobFromStream.

Sample code:

```
var myStream = getSomeStream();
var myStreamLength = getSomeStreamLength();
blobService.createBlockBlobFromStream(
    containerName,
    'my-awesome-stream-blob',
    myStream,
    myStreamLength,
    function(error, result, response){
        if(error){
            console.log("Couldn't upload stream");
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Stream uploaded successfully');
        }
    });
```

However I do not know how to generate myStream  and myStreamLength from an array.

Comment: One thing you could do is serialize the array as string (JSON.stringify(array)) and then upload that using createBlockBlobFromText. Will that be an acceptable solution?

Comment: @GauravMantri Unfortunately not, since the data exceeds the 64MB limit of the FromText function

Answer (score 0):

You might instead want to use [`createWriteStreamToBlockBlob`](http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#createWriteStreamToBlockBlob) function, which might be easier to upload stream to Azure storage. You no longer need to worry about stream length there. And then you can use the following code to generate stream from an array.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var Readable = require('stream').Readable;

var accountName = "youraccountname";
var accessKey = "youraccountkey";
var host = "https://yourhost.blob.core.windows.net";
var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accessKey, host);

var myArray = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", 788, 12.3];

var rs = Readable();

for(item of myArray) {
    rs.push(String(item));
}
rs.push(null);  // indicates end-of-file basically - the end of the stream

rs.pipe(blobSvc.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob('mycontainer', 'mystream.txt'));
```

[See here](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook) for more info on how to use streams properly.